# MySQL Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' error

Tags: mysql

I just installed MySQL 5.7 on CentOS 7 and root password is configured.

MySQL login on my localhost is successful as below.

```
[root@test]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 34
Server version: 5.7.30 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```

However, a web application that I need to connect to MySQL says as below.

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
The database connection failed: the host or super user parameters must be wrong.
```

mysqld.log says

```
2020-06-26T05:31:47.878390Z 27 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-06-26T05:36:12.328126Z 28 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-06-26T05:53:18.872033Z 29 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-06-26T05:53:35.232340Z 30 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-06-26T06:06:34.293625Z 35 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The password is correct and it is fresh installed MySQL.
I tried mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables to remove my password and it works without password but sql scripts cannot run.
Thus, password configuration is required for security purposes.

phpmyadmin is accessible with the same MySQL ID and PW.

Will it be the web application problem?(but I doubt it because it is an initial setup stage) or there is something that I can do on the MySQL side?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to reinstall mysql and add another user for example `CREATE USER 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123'`

Comment: @Mantykora7 Thanks for your comment. However, I already reinstalled it three times and It has to be "root". I assume this error message should not say "using password: No". it should be yes because I typed the password.

Comment: This is a virtual machine?

Comment: @Mantykora7 Yes it is and it is on a public cloud. Selinux and Firewall are both off.

Comment: Can you install something else for testing? For example ubuntu server. Have you tried sudo su and then >mysql?

Comment: Try options: `mysqladmin -u root -p password` `mysql -u root -p` `sudo mysql -u root -p` `mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -uroot -p` xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - server IP

Comment: Or try `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get autoclean`, `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: @Mantykora7 Thanks for your answer but i found another way to run the web application. Thanks for your help!